# Undefined message displayed when uploading a file with ckeditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, ruby-on-rails-5

I upgraded ckeditor gem from `4.2.4` to `4.3.0` and now the upload file is not working. I select an image, click on "Send to server" and a javascript alert shows up with just the message `undefined`. No console messages or error and in my terminal I only get the following log:

```
"POST /pictures HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.6002
```

What can be causing this problem? I'm using `ruby 2.5.3` and `rails 5.2.0`

[image]

I do get a Internal Server Error before when ckeditor is loading the moonocolor skin with Balloonpanel.css and balloontoolbal.css but that shouldn't be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.  It would appear that AssetResponse in the ckeditor/application_controller is not populating the model attributes.  asset.save is failing validation because the attributes are blank.  Here's what I'm getting in byebug.

```
   10:   def respond_with_asset(asset)
   11:     asset_response = Ckeditor::AssetResponse.new(asset, request)
   12: 
=> 13:     if asset.save
   14:       render asset_response.success(config.relative_url_root)
   15:     else
   16:       render asset_response.errors
   17:     end
(byebug) asset
#<Ckeditor::Picture id: nil, attachable_id: nil, attachable_type: nil, asset_type: "image", description: nil, sort_by: "", visible: false, data_file_name: nil, data_content_type: nil, data_file_size: nil, deleted_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, row_order: nil, data_fingerprint: nil>
(byebug)
```

Comment: No.  There is a problem in the build.  https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/829#issuecomment-453027294